# How to modify an Office (Word, Excel) file in sharepoint programmatically

Tags: excel, word

I need to Open and modify a document that resides on a Sharepoint Document Library.

These changes on the file are done during an event generated by a Document Library, so I must change it by code.

Is there any way to do that? I tried to use  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word but without success.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ziba,

OpenXML SDK is what you are looking for, OpenXML SDK can help you edit and create word, excel and other documents programmatically and it works great with SharePoint!

Following links can help you:
[Modifying Open XML Documents using the SharePoint Object Model](https://web.archive.org/web/20151113062457/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/ericwhite/archive/2008/12/12/modifying-open-xml-documents-using-the-sharepoint-object-model.aspx)
[SharePoint and OpenXML](https://web.archive.org/web/20140718081719/http://sharepointblog.acando.com:80/2012/11/08/sharepoint-and-open-xml)

ERIC White has written many articles on SharePoint with OpenXML:
http://ericwhite.com/blog/category/open-xml/

I hope this helps